# How to plot a gaussian curve with the value of peak given?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am plotting a gaussian curve as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

mu = 840
base = 5
y_a = y_b = base
x_a = 0
x_b = 1439

x = np.linspace(0, 1440, 1440)
sigma = (x_b-x_a)/6

plt.plot(x, (stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)))
plt.show()
```

and this gives a graph as follows:

[Image from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb4L7.png)

In the y-axis we see that the peak value goes a bit more than 0.00150.

I would like to know if there is a way where in we can define a peak value and that peak is reached at the value of `mu` and the values between the peak and the 0 and the peak and the `x_b` are distributed in such a way that they form a gaussian curve

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify what you want the peak probability density to be, you're also specifying your standard deviation because of the [normalization condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). Here your standard deviation must be `sigma = 1.0/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*K)` where your desired peak probability is `K`.